# How to upload 3 bamfiles in R shiny and then to merge as one?

Tags: r, file-upload, shiny, merge

Good afternoon. I want to upload 3 bamfiles in R shiny and then to elaborate as one within a function that I wrote.

ui.R

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidPage(
        titlePanel("MY BAM FILES MERGER"),
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                fileInput("bam",
                          "Choose BAM files from directory",
                          multiple = TRUE,
                          accept=c('.bam')),
                                 
                downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')
            ),
            mainPanel(
                tableOutput('contents')
            )
        )
    )
)
```

server.R

```
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=10000*1024^2)


options(warn=-1)
library(Rsamtools)
library(Biostrings)
library(shiny)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library("readxl")

function(input, output) {
    getData <- reactive({
        inFile <- input$bam
        if (is.null(inFile)){
            return(NULL)
        } else {
             bamFiles <- list.files(
                 path= 'datapath',
                 pattern="*.bam$",
                 full.names = TRUE)
             destination="Merged_bam1"
            #Merging 3 BAMS files
            
                #inFile=list.files(input$bam$datapath[1:3])
                
                
                Merged_bam=mergeBam(bamFiles, destination, region = GRanges(),
                                    overwrite = TRUE, header = character(), byQname = FALSE,
                                    addRG = FALSE, compressLevel1 = FALSE, indexDestination = FALSE)
```

I tried to use for loop but then uploading one by one the files. mergeBam function need to see in the same time all files not one by one.
In desktop version working properly list.files with mergeBam. in R shiny I tried different combinations but I cannot bit the correct.
Please anyone to help?

Comment: what is the error or exact problem with your current code? I don't have bamfiles so it's hard to reproduce your problem

Comment: Thank you for your answer....my problem it was that I wanted it many files to act as one. I resolve by changing mergeBams(bamFiles... with mergeBams(inFile$datapath .... and worked...thank you